# Can You Trigger a Cloud Function In Response to Increased Traffic to Your Website?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way for me to run a cloud function to update some data whenever there is lots of activity to one of my pages? sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions does not have any triggers that automatically respond to the load on a web site.  You will have to find some other way to gauge that traffic, and then perhaps invoke an [HTTP trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) directly.

If you want to see the complete list of trigger types, see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling).

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how to monitor this activity? I'm pretty lost, any help is much appreciated

Comment: I have no idea. You should consult the documentation or customer support for whatever it is that you're using for hosting.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know there is no such thing as a direct trigger between a spike of events in service A and cloud function (unless the service A is itself a cloud function, that would indeed scale).

However it exists [*second party trigger with stackdriver*](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/logging) that allows you to define rules that once hit would deliver an event to a pub/sub topic that a cloud function of your choice can suscribe to. Be cautious with what you intend to do with your cloud function, you may have concurency issues depending the technology of the database you want to modify. In other word, try to be as idempotent as possible.

I think you may be interested by this community [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-pubsub-drainer).